# How to handle the popus or alers that can occur any where inside the code in selenium

Tags: selenium

I got a scenario where the popup's/alerts may occur any where inside the code.
They may occur during the page loading also. anywhere between the actions of users where we don't have the specific idea.
How to handle this scenario.
Please suggest.

Comment: Personally, I dont think it's a good test. You couldnot control when the pop-up displays means you could not control your test scenario and it's not recommended in automation. I strongly suggest you should not continue this idea.

Comment: If you still want, let's use try/catch to catch alertException, then do anything you want, then continue your test

Comment: How about the idea of implementing a listener to keep an eye on if a pop-up/alert has occurred.

Comment: Could you please elobarate a bit @null pointer, I have an idea of implementing two run two separate threads. One will keep eye on popups and one will execute the code. Don't know how it will works but looking for other more suggestions

Comment: @bharadwaj : A better way is to give something at least a try and then be here to get suggestions. Also you can search for "how to implement listener in code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a thread running in background which will check for alerts.In case any alert is found then do accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the alerts, one technique you can do is use JavaScript injection to disable alerts completely.

```
(JavaScriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("window.alert = function(){}");
```